# How to group values over different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df =
    ID    HOUR    GROUP_1     GROUP_2     GROUP_3     DURATION
    1     7       AAA         AAA         BBB         20
    2     7       BBB         AAA         CCC         22
    3     7       BBB         BBB         BBB         21
    4     8       AAA         AAA         AAA         23
    5     8       CCC         AAA         CCC         25
    6     9       CCC         CCC         CCC         28
```

I can calculate average `DURATION` per `HOUR` as follows:

```
grouped = df.groupby("HOUR").DURATION.mean().reset_index()
```

Now I need to also group the entried by group values stored in `GROUP_1`, `GROUP_2` and `GROUP_3`. I want to consider the occurance of a group only once per row, i.e. if `AAA` is repeated two times in the first row, it should be considered only once.

The result should be:

```
result =
GROUP  HOUR  MEAN_DURATION
AAA    7     21
AAA    8     24
BBB    7     21
...
```

I know how to count the occurance of each group per row, but don't know how to put everything together to get the expected result:

```
df.filter(regex="^GROUP").stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your group variables to one column, drop duplicated groups in each row and then group by `hour` and `group` to take the mean:

```
(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID', 'HOUR', 'DURATION'], value_name='GROUP')
 .drop('variable', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
 .groupby(['HOUR', 'GROUP']).DURATION.mean()
 .reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to add a restrction for considering only groups `AAA` and `BBB` from the list `to_be_considered=["AAA","BBB"]`. Is it possible?

Comment: You can filter the result with `.isin()` method. i.e, if the above result is `mean_df`, then `mean_df[mean_df.GROUP.isin(to_be_considered)]` should filter out other group results.

Answer (score 0):

Using to `numpy` to `melt`

```
groups = df.filter(like='GROUP').values

w = groups.shape[1]
hours = df.HOUR.values.repeat(w)
durtn = df.DURATION.values.repeat(w)

d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(HOUR=hours, GROUP=groups.ravel(), DURATION=durtn)
).drop_duplicates()

d1

    DURATION GROUP  HOUR
0         20   AAA     7
2         20   BBB     7
3         22   BBB     7
4         22   AAA     7
5         22   CCC     7
6         21   BBB     7
9         23   AAA     8
12        25   CCC     8
13        25   AAA     8
15        28   CCC     9
```

then `groupby` + `mean` + `reset_index`

```
d1.groupby(['HOUR', 'GROUP']).mean().reset_index()

   HOUR GROUP  DURATION
0     7   AAA        21
1     7   BBB        21
2     7   CCC        22
3     8   AAA        24
4     8   CCC        25
5     9   CCC        28
```

---

***all together***

```
groups = df.filter(like='GROUP').values

w = groups.shape[1]
hours = df.HOUR.values.repeat(w)
durtn = df.DURATION.values.repeat(w)

pd.DataFrame(
    dict(HOUR=hours, GROUP=groups.ravel(), DURATION=durtn)
).drop_duplicates().groupby(
    ['HOUR', 'GROUP']
).mean().reset_index()
```